# Magento what is a fatal error call to a member function? and how do I edit Controller.php

Tags: php, magento

I've have had a good ole search on here to replicate an error I've been receiving in my Magento 1.9 installation (there are a few related posts, but nothing specific)

With my error logs turned on in index.php I receive the following error, in my browser, when trying to add/edit admin users in the backend:

Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in /hsphere/local/home/my-site-user/my-site/designs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php on line 93

Line 93 is:

->setData('action', $this->getUrl('*/permissions_user/save'));

I would be grateful if anybody could point me in the right direction to solve this issue!

Best wishes

David

Comment: you're doing `$obj->setData` where `$obj` is not an object, exactly as the error message says.

Comment: Try clear folder `var/cache`. Did you make changes with output's configuration for modules?

Comment: Thanks, Aleksandr - it all went pear shaped when I added SOAP XML-RPC-USERS & ROLES to connect to a external Back Office System. I deleted the contents of var/cache - the recompile is also disabled..

Comment: Also..thanks for your reply too Marc..apologies, I don't fully understand the $obj->setData model - I'm trying to learn (that's why I signed up at stakoverflow) cheers

Comment: I got got this sorted - I installed an extension to manage admin emails. This seemed to have removed the admin.xml file from /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/ I uploaded the the file from my original installation..emptied out the cache and is fine now!